# Javascript functions and declaring

Tags: javascript, function

When working with functions in JavaScript, are variables declared as parameters in a function different from variables declared within the function itself?

For example, is

```
function functionName (var1, var2)
```

different to

```
Function (var1, var2) {
    Var VarName;
}
```

In the second example, could `var1` be declared where `varName` is declared? If not, why?

Comment: Please use proper casing, it is important in programming. Make sure that the code snippets you want to ask about are at least syntactically valid.

Answer (score 0):

`var1` and `var2` are parameter variables, they automatically get their values from the arguments provided when the function is called.

Variables declared with `var` inside the function body are local variables of the function.

Parameter variables are automatically made local to the function. You can have

```
var var1;
```

in the function, but it's redundant and has no effect. It doesn't create a new variable or override the value of the parameter (unless you include an initializer).

```js
function myFunc(var1, var2) {
  var var1;
  var var2 = 3;
  var newVar;
  console.log(var1, var2, newVar);
}

myFunc(1, 2);
```